# How to remove the outermost curly braces and everything before and after them in R?

Tags: r, string

Let's assume, I have a string as follows:

```
"A fancy ! nametag here! {{These} are the contents!}"
```

I would like to make it:

```
"{These} are the contents!"
```

There can be curly braces between the outermost curly braces.

Since, I couldn't form a regular expression, I wrote a code that iterates through every character, and when it passes the first opening curly brace, it stores this information into a separate variable i.e. something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
#This is the input
"A fancy ! nametag here! {{These} are the contents!}" %>%
  #Let's split them to a vector, so we can iterate character by character
  strsplit(split = "") %>%
  #Strsplit is vectorized, and returns a list as it should, but we need a vector (the first element of that list) at the moment
  unlist %>%
  {
    #We need to track whether we are inside parentheses
    insideParentheses = 0
    #Here we accrue the name tag
    nametag = ""
    #Here we accrue the contens
    contents = ""
    #And then we iterate character by character...
    for(char in .){
      #Checking and marking up whether we go into the next level of parentheses or come out
      insideParentheses = insideParentheses + (char=="{") - (char=="}")
      #If we are completely outside parentheses, we add the character to the name tag
      if(!insideParentheses) {nametag = paste0(nametag,char)}
      #If we have entered the most outer parentheses, but haven't got out yet, we write a character to contents
      if(insideParentheses) {contents = paste0(contents,char)}
    }
    
    #After each and every character have been iterated, we create a list
    list(
      contents %>% sub("\\{","",.) #Since the very first parenthesis is written to the contents, it needs to be removed
      ) %>%
      setNames(nametag %>% sub("\\}$", "", .)) #Since the very last parenthesis is written to the name tag, it needs to be removed too
  } %>%
  print

$`A fancy ! nametag here! `
[1] "{These} are the contents!"
```

However, this solution has many downsides (slow, consumes memory, not vectorized etc).

So can this be achieved using a regular expression(s)?

Comment: How about the input `"{one} and {two}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sub`, capture everything between the first `{` and last `}`. Return the capture group.

```r
str <- "A fancy ! nametag here! {{These} are the contents!}"

sub("^.*?\\{(.*)\\}.*$", "\\1", str)
#> [1] "{These} are the contents!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexpr`/`regmatches`.

```
> regmatches(x, regexpr(r"{(?<=\{).*(?=\})}", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "{These} are the contents!"
```

*Data:*

```
x <- "A fancy ! nametag here! {{These} are the contents!} foo"
```